# MySQL - Execute stored procedure asynchronously

Tags: python, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**Question**
How can I execute a stored procedure in MySQL, asynchronously? I want to be able to call my procedure and have it silently run in the background, without the caller having to wait for it to finish.

**Research**
I've looked at making an `EVENT`; however, that appears to only have a time scheduled trigger. I'd prefer to only execute the procedure upon a manual trigger, versus having it constantly running in the background.

**More Details**
The program that would call the procedure is written in Python. I'm open to a Python solution, provided that I don't have to add any "big" modules (I don't want to install another ORM, as I already use peewee).

Comment: You could always just run the python script in the background: `./foo.py &`

Comment: That won't really solve the problem. I need the client to be able to fire off that procedure and then be free to go off and do other tasks; this program is much more involved than a simple script. Additionally, the procedure that it starts can be quite time consuming.